# getText() android studio

Tags: java, android, edittext

Soy estudiante y solo empiezo con android studio y quiero hacer el funcionamiento del login. Tengo todas las variables declaradas pero no me deja usar el método `.getText()` para `editText`.

```
package com.example.appespejo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

View signUpButton = findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
View textLogin = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
View textPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        Setup
    setup();
    }


private void setup() {

    signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String inputname = textLogin.getText()
        }
    });

}
}
```

No me ni aparece. Como lo puedo solucionar?
Uso la version 4 de android studio.

Comment: Considera poner tu código como texto, no como imagen. Por otra parte, en el código mostrado no puede verse de qué tipo es el objeto `textLogin`, fundamental para poder intuir lo que está ocurriendo aquí. Y, aunque en las sugerencias del IDE no te muestre el método, al menos prueba a completarlo: **`textLogin.getText();`**  y si marca error entonces ya hablaremos...

Comment: Deberías adjuntar todo el código, en formato código y no en imagen. Como se dijo, no sabemos que objeto es textLogin

Comment: Hola @Ekaterina, trata de agregar siempre el código como texto para que sea legigle para todos los miembros de la comunidad.  Agrega como declaras textLogin por favor, saluds.

Comment: Perdon, ahora voy

Comment: @EkaterinaSkripnikova gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque los `EditText` extienden de `View` lo recomendable es definir la variable por su tipo, en este caso debe ser `EditText` y no `View`, lo mismo para el botón:

```
//View signUpButton = findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
//View textLogin = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
//View textPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
Button signUpButton = findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
EditText textLogin = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
EditText textPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
```

de esta forma ahora podrás acceder sin problema al método `getText()` de tus `EditText`:

```
String inputname = textLogin.getText().toString();
```

---

Los import utilizados para el `Button` y `EditText` son :

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Comment: Ahora lo que pasa es que Button y EditText me sale en rojo deciendo Cannot resolve symbol 'Button'

Comment: Lo que sucede es que falta el "import" para usar las clases Button y EditText, posicionate en donde se muestra en rojo y da Alt+Enter, se agregarán automáticamente los import o simplemente agrega los import como menciono en la actualización de mi respuesta.